# How to disable google load balancer logging?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How to disable google load balancer logging? We are currently generating 30TB (Yes TB not GB) of logs per month that we don't care about and never look at. It's quite a waste or resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Google Cloud Platform** console, from **Stackdriver Logging** section, navigate to **Resource usage**, choose **Cloud HTTP Load Balancer** and select **Disable log source** from the options on the right. https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/usage

You can also see option to create **Exclusion filter**.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#excluding-resource

To delete the previous logs

```
gcloud logging logs delete projects/<PROJECT-ID>/logs/requests
```

Comment: Yes Google added this a while back. We are already using this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Google Cloud Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#logging) and [Stackdriver Logging documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) and also going over the Cloud Console UI and the [REST API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/), there is currently no way to disable Stackdriver logging for Google Cloud Load balancer.

Also, Google currently does not charge a fee for storing the Stackdriver logs.

If your concern is that it is hard to search through the logs, you can always [filter logs while viewing on Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters) to help you narrow down only the items of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable logging for a HTTP / HTTPS Loadbalancer, see [GCP Loadbalancing Docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#disabling_or_modifying_logging_on_an_existing_backend_service)

If your traffic is coming to a GKE Kubernetes Ingress, you can also disable logging via a `BackendConfig` manifest, see [GKE Docs on HTTP access logging](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#http_logging)